# ASP.Net Core Web API Authentication with Facebook

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API developed with ASP.Net Core. I also have a client app developed with Next.js and it uses NextAuth.js to handle the authentication.

In the UI, when a user is authenticated, I have access to the access token from Facebook.
My question is how can I use this access token to authenticate the requests sent to the back-end API.

This is the back-end code used to register the Facebook authentication scheme (it is all standard):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddFacebook(
        facebookOptions =>
        {
            facebookOptions.AppId = "<my_app_id>";
            facebookOptions.AppSecret = "<my_app_secret>";
        });
```

I want to construct a Postman request that can authenticate my user using a specific access token but I do not know where to put this access token and whether this is possible at all.
Just sending the request like this (without any modifications) results in visualizing the Facebook login page.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Are you doing this in an .net core API or MVC app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Asp.NetCore project integrates Facebook login. After logging in, the token you get can only access protected resources in the current project, such as: `[Authorize]`.

If you want to access Facebook's resources, you need to write your own code to get the token and then access the resources.

[1. How to Get Facebook Access Token in a couple of minutes: 2020 guide](https://elfsight.com/blog/2017/10/how-to-get-facebook-access-token/)

[2. How to get current user access token from Facebook SDK in C#? Not the App access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390430/how-to-get-current-user-access-token-from-facebook-sdk-in-c-not-the-app-access)

After you get facebook access_token, then you can access Facebook's resources.